# how to set "data-" of rails f.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, select

I use rails 4.

```
<%= f.select :industry_id, options_from_collection_for_select([], "id", "name"),
'data-option-dependent' => true,
'data-option-observed' => 'pre_industry_id',
'data-option-url' => '/industries/:pre_industy_id:/sub_industry.json',
'data-option-key-method' => :id,
'data-option_value-method' => :name %>
```

but...

In result, data-attributes don't appear.

```
<select id="review_industry_id" name="review[industry_id]"></select>
```

Comment: Put all the data attributes in side {} and have a try

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh how is it supposed to help?

Comment: @MarekLipka according to this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select

It will expect a empty hash and then all the options.. and i believe your answer is correct.

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh there's nowhere any hint that your solution could help in the link you provided.

Comment: @MarekLipka it is there please have a look like select("album[]", "genre", %w[rap rock country], {}, { index: nil }). in the documentation.

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh you misunderstood this a little bit. Look at my answer for reference.

Comment: @MarekLipka yep got your point .. but seems like he needs something else. please have a look in my answer

Answer (score 5):

Pass a `data` hash as an option for `select`'s `html_options` argument:

```
<%= f.select :industry_id,
             options_from_collection_for_select([], "id", "name"),
             {},
             data: {
                 'option-dependent' => true,
                 'option-observed' => 'pre_industry_id',
                 'option-url' => '/industries/:pre_industy_id:/sub_industry.json',
                 'option-key-method' => :id,
                 'option_value-method' => :name } %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be passed also as `html_options` param?

Answer (score 3):

[`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) helper takes two options parameters. The first one is `options`, the second one is `html_options`. Since you're interested in the second one, you should put empty hash (`{}`) in place of `options` param:

```
<%= f.select :industry_id, options_from_collection_for_select([], 'id', 'name'), {},
'data-option-dependent' => true,
'data-option-observed' => 'pre_industry_id',
'data-option-url' => '/industries/:pre_industy_id:/sub_industry.json',
'data-option-key-method' => :id,
'data-option_value-method' => :name %>
```

Comment: @user3580287 did you try my solution? Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Your approach should work. Not sure why someone would downvote it.

Comment: @ChrisPeters one of downvotes seems to be Sabyasachi Ghosh's revenge. But the second one remains mystery.

Comment: @MarekLipka you approach should also work. if it's on select.

Comment: @MarekLipka I am not here to take revenge on you. Its forum and its all about sharing knowledge nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I Believe this will solve your problem

```
<%= f.select :industry_id, options_for_select(@array.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id, {'data-option-dependent' => true,
'data-option-observed' => 'pre_industry_id'}] }) %>
```

Comment: It will insert these attributes inside of `option` tags istead of `select` tag. This is not what OP meant.

Comment: I believe he needs something like this. let the question creator remove the confusion.

Comment: No, OP clearly want these attributes in `select` and it's quite obvious.